# how to redirect GAP output to a text file on a local drive?

Tags: gap-system

Example

```
 m1;
[ [ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 ] ]
```

in the Windows version of the [GAP system](http://www.gap-system.org/), how do it redirect any output to a text file on a local drive?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `LogTo` command to save inputs and outputs of the whole GAP session, or you may use `PrintTo` to print the object to the text file.

Enter `?LogTo` and `?PrintTo' in GAP to see the documentation.

P.S. If you prefer to ask questions about GAP in StackExchange framework, I'd recommend to try to ask them at Mathematics Q&A site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap).